# Kendo- Chart inside Listview. One chart per datasource record

Tags: kendo-ui

Has anyone got a working sample of a chart embedded inside a listView using Kendo?

The chart must use the same datasource as the ListView.

There is a partial sample on the Kendo forums http://www.telerik.com/forums/sparkline-inside-listview-html-template-

The last snippet doesnt quite work for me.

```
function createChart(){
var data = this.dataSource.data();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var item = this.wrapper.find("[data-uid='" + data[i].uid + "']");
         var chart = item.find(".chart");
         chart.kendoChart({
             //....
         });
    };
```

Cheers

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should use the dataBound event if you want to initialize a widget inside a client template of a listview or grid.

Here is an example that shows it with a Grid, same approach can be used for a ListView.
Let's assume you have a div with the class of chart inside your client template.

```
dataBound:function(){
      $(".chart").kendoChart({ 
           //chart options
       })
}
```

Here is [one](http://jsbin.com/oletef/3/edit) demo where the data for the chart is hard-coded. And here is [another one](http://jsbin.com/oletef/7) that actually uses the grid dataItem for that row to get the collection for the chart.